# How to get the YesIntent run after a specific intent is run in Alexa Skill

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've been trying to find out how to make the AMAZON.YesIntent run after another intent is triggered. I have searched around and tried different solutions however they never work.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger your `AMAZON.YesIntent` handler from another intent handler.?

Comment: @CicilThomas Yes I have even set a variable so when a specific intent is hit, the variable becomes true, then the yes intent should see if the variable is true and output a certain response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call any handler from another intent handler.

**alexa-nodejs-sdk v1**
For `alexa-nodejs-sdk` v1 you can use

```
'SomeOtherIntent': function() {
   // Do your stuff here

   // Now to call AMAZON.YesIntent intent handler
   this.emit('AMAZON.YesIntent');
}
```

**alexa-nodejs-sdk v2**
For `alexa-nodejs-sdk` v2 you can import the target handle function (if it's in a different module) or just invoke the it directly and pass in the `handlerinput`.

```
const SomeOtherIntentHandler = {
   canHandle(handlerInput) {
      const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
      return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
         && request.intent.name === 'SomeOtherIntent';
   },

   handle(handlerInput) {
      // Do your stuff here

      // Now to call AMAZON.YesIntent intent handler
      return amazonYesIntentHandler.handle(handlerInput);
   }
}
```